# Understanding of Consumer Producer Thread Problem

Tags: java, multithreading

The code below demonstrates the Producer-Consumer problem for Threads in Java. I am having trouble understanding the output of this code. Based on my understanding,

1. producer thread starts, followed by the consumer thread.
2. producer thread adds 1 item to the list, and calls notify() but there are no waiting threads. list size is 1.
3. producer thread adds another item to the list and calls notify() but there are no waiting threads. list size is 2.
4. Since list size is 2, the wait() method on producer thread is executed.
5. The consumer thread runs and removes an item from the list. consumer thread then calls the notify() method. list size is now 1.

In Step 5, after calling the notify() method in the consumer thread, does it proceed on to the waiting producer thread and add another item to the list? Or does it continue removing another item till the list size is 0? From the actual output of the code as shown below, it seems like the latter is true but I thought it should enter the producer thread because the consumer thread calls the notify method and the producer thread is waiting.

Please correct my misunderstanding of this code.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Processor processor = new Processor();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    processor.producer();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    processor.consumer();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

}


class Processor {

    private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final int UPPER_LIMIT = 2;
    private static final int LOWER_LIMIT = 0;
    private int value = 0;

    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public void producer() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(lock) {
            while (true) {
                if (list.size() == UPPER_LIMIT) {
                    System.out.println("Waiting for removing items...");
                    // lock.wait() because we synchronized on the `lock`
                    lock.wait(); // if just wait() means we are waiting on the Processor itself
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Adding: " + value);
                    list.add(value);
                    value++;
                    // we can call the notify - because the other thread will be notified
                    // only when it is in a waiting state
                    lock.notify();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void consumer() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(lock) {
            while (true) {
                if (list.size() == LOWER_LIMIT) {
                    System.out.println("Waiting for adding items...");
                    lock.wait(); 
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Removing: " + list.remove(list.size() - 1));
                    lock.notify();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
// Output
Adding: 0
Adding: 1
Waiting for removing items...
Removing: 1
Removing: 0
Waiting for adding items...
Adding: 2
Adding: 3
Waiting for removing items...
Removing: 3
Removing: 2
Waiting for adding items...
Adding: 4
Adding: 5
Waiting for removing items...
Removing: 5
Removing: 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing one item, the call of `notify` in the consumer *does not* cause the producer to continue executing immediately because the consumer is still holding the lock of the monitor. It is not until the consumer `wait`s, that it relinquishes the monitor lock, and the producer can acquire it.

Of course, the consumer can also relinquish the lock by exiting the `synchronized` block, but that's never going to happen :)

See the documentation for [`notify`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notify()):

> Wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor. [...]
>
> The awakened thread will not be able to proceed until the current thread relinquishes the lock on this object.

Therefore, the consumer consumes everything, then `wait`s, and that's when the producer starts running. And the same situation happens again, in the producer thread. The producer does not give up the lock, until the upper limit is reached and it `wait`s.

One way to achieve "consumers consumes one item and then the producer starts producing another" is, in the consumer, to put the synchronised block outside the infinite loop, and `sleep` outside the synchronised block. This gives the produce a chance to acquire the lock and add items.

```
public void consumer() throws InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            if (list.size() == LOWER_LIMIT) {
                System.out.println("Waiting for adding items...");
                lock.wait();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Removing: " + list.remove(list.size() - 1));
                lock.notify();
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
Adding: 0
Adding: 1
Waiting for removing items...
Removing: 1
Adding: 2
Waiting for removing items...
Removing: 2
Adding: 3
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. So both `notify()` and `wait()` must be called together then it will pass the monitor lock to the producer to acquire it? Only `wait()` can pass on the monitor lock to another thread but `notify()` is just to tell the producer thread to "get ready" as it waits for the condition on the `wait()` method to be met.

Comment: @Jessica `wait` is just one of the ways to give up the monitor lock. Another way is just to exit the synchronised block, but of course that can’t happen in your code.

Comment: Oh, I see! So if there is no `wait()` in the thread A and only `notify()`, does this mean that the other thread B will run only when thread A has finished executing everything in its synchronized block?

Comment: @Jessica yes, assuming that B is also waiting on the lock that A holds, of course.

Comment: Great! this clears things up thanks